# How to destroy instance of view controller after performing segue

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2, segue

I use **performSegueWithIdentifier** to navigate between views controllers

I have a tableView with multiple rows, when a row is actioned, i call a webViewController to play selected ressource with segue

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("Play", sender: nil)
```

Associate with :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "Play") {
        let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! WebViewController
        detailVC.courseToPlay = self.courseToPlay
    }
}
```

And, on WebViewController, i've a button to goBack on the list, whose i want to destroy instance of webViewController on goBack

I've not NavigationController in my storyBoard, so, this line doesn't work

```
navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

I use segue again to goBack :

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("closePlayer", sender: nil)
```

But each segue action instance a new view controller and they're never really free from memory, they seems to just be hiddens

eg : in Safari debugger i can see a lot of page and i can always interact with these in console

How to properly 'destroy' a view when scene change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is a modal segue you can use

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

To dismiss the webViewController instead of another segue

Answer (score 7):

Swift3:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope it can help you.

Thanks